# Django - Queryset to get all related details to a Model

Tags: python, django

I have a Book model which has multiple authors, genres. Here are the models which have all the ForeignKey relations.

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Genre(models.Model):
    genre_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Book_author(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

class Book_genre(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
```

**views.py**

```
def book_detail(request, book_id):
    book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
    # how can i get iterated multiple authors, books attached to book dictionary
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'book': book})
```

**book object example:**

```
book = {
    title: 'some title',
    authors: [
              {
                 id: 1,
                 name: 'name1'
              },
              {
                 id: 2,
                 name: 'name2'
              }
    ],
    genres: [
         {
            id: 1,
            genre_name: 'somegenre1' 
         },
         {
            id: 1,
            genre_name: 'somegenre2' 
         }
    ]
}
```

How can i access Book related authors, genre's in my views.py method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change anything in your view, for reverse lookups you can call model's reverse relation accessor and avail all related objects.

In your template,

```
title : {{ book.title }}
authors : {% for item in book.book_author_set.all %} {{ item.author.name }} {% endfor %}
genres : {% for item in book.book_genre_set.all %} {{ item.genre.genre_name }} {% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks, that works in template, but i want to get those authors, genres related to book in my `views.py` method and modify them, here what i did `book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id) book.book_genre_set.all() 
 pprint(vars(book.genre))` but it gives me `Attribute error` `'Book' object has no attribute 'genre'` how can i get them

Comment: Try, `for item in book.book_genre_set.all(): item.genre.genre_name`.

Comment: ya i got it, thanks again if i have any queries further i will post here